# How to ask to my boss to pay Cloud Services that was bought in the company name?

Tags: software-industry, management

First of all, my boss is very good and comprehensive person. I work on a Software Development company, and, currently, all our services are running on AWS system. But, the proxies that we need couldn't run on Amazon service. So my boss asked for me to use the free trials on other Cloud Services Company and when I had find it the functional platform for us I should sent to him the pricing. After some search I figure out that our proxies could run on Google Cloud and Azure systems.

As you probably know, to use the free trial counts, you must insert your credit card. So a inserted my, obviously, because I want just to test. After I tell my boss that we have our proxies running in those systems, I sent to him the prices of each instance. But as we are tied to dates I said to him that we could resolve the price and count later and that we should give attentions to other tasks that were more important. He agreed with me. The problem is that the time of free trial expired on Google Cloud and now I have been charged in $9,00 (which in Brazil is a considerable value). How can I ask for him to pay this value without been greed or something like that?

Comment: It's not greed to ask the company to reimburse you for their expenses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Send him a copy of the invoice, or receipt if you have already paid along with the login and other details and ask for reimbursement. This is not being greedy, it's normal.

Also ask him for the details to change for the default billing so that your card doesn't get billed in future.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why?

Comment: It means you've gained a stalker.  I have a couple.  You can say that you like puppies and babies and they'll downvote you.  I see it as a badge of honor.

Comment: @WesleyLong I do like puppies and babies :-)

Answer (score 1):

So Kilisi has the right answer on this.  There are 2 things you did wrong here:

1. If you need a credit card for a corporate item, either get a corporate card or an agreement in writing UPFRONT that they will will cover any bills.  Do not sign up to anything on your own dime.  At best you will jump through hoops to get it paid. At worst you may find they don't (or can't) cover it.(I've seen corporate expenses like this that had to be invoiced with a purchase order, expensing it wasn't allowed)
2. I've used all the main cloud providers (a while since I used Google) and they allow spending limits to be set.  Even using your own card it would have been prudent to set a sensible limit and once reached talk to your boss to get a corporate card to go further.

So while I'm sympathetic, this situation could have been easily avoided with a little thought. Reflect and learn from this.

Comment: In this case, it's in the company's best interest to keep the Google Cloud and Azure accounts running well.  That's likely to get things going faster.  When such expenses are one-time and the company has already reaped all the benefit, it's hard to get repaid.  In this case, the expenses and benefit are continuing.